# Web application deployment under embedded Tomcat 7.0.32

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

We have been using tomcat 7.0.19 successfully in embedded mode. However recently due to some fixes in our area of concern we decided to move to tomcat 7.0.32. Most things work as expected with same code and newer version, however the war deployment for some reason has'nt worked well. I have a couple of servlets registered with my tomcat. Facing below 2 issues,

1. Has something changed from 7.0.19 to 7.0.32 from embedded tomcat behavior. To detail this out let me explain the behavior difference, with 7.0.19, i could deploy my application and when i hit the "host:port/contextpath" it loaded the applications start page (i.e. welcome page, this page is UI centric and does not need a server intervention, so none of my servlets get called). However with 7.0.32 the same url results in my servlet being called.
2. So to debug the problem, i commented most of my code so that i have a vanilla tomcat implementation, just the very basic stuff, i.e. setting the engine name, default host, setting host properties, adding a connector (nio, with default properties) and deploying a war. No servlets and other things, just to check if the very basic stuff works. To my surprise when i ran this code it still failed with the same problem within my servlet, how did that happen, now that my code is commented it does not register any servlets, still where does it find it from? Does embedded tomcat store some old references, which are not getting cleaned on subsequent runs? I tried changing the port, but that too didn't help.

I am hitting the wall here, not able to understand this wierd behavior, if i figure out #2, only then can i make some progress on #1.

Thanks in advance,

Vikram

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code? I'd say it's impossible to help without looking at the code (web.xml and maybe a servlet).

Comment: Please try pinpointing the actual version that introduced behaviours above. Examine the versions between 7.0.20 and 7.0.31, it's not that much work using binary searching methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problems were.

In reverse order,

2 - This actually was a weird behavior with the vanilla embedded tomcat code too invoking the servlets which never were registered in the first place. The problem here was with eclipse, for some reason it picked up the old reference of my class. The moment i ran the same code from outside of eclipse i.e. via command prompt, things were back to normal.

1 - This problem was related to web deployment, in my code i was additionally setting my classloader into WebappLoader and eventually adding my application jars into it. This for whatever reasons worked fine with 7.0.19, however did not with 7.0.32, the moment i externalized all my jars to be loaded during application startup via classpath this problem too was resolved.

Thanks,

Vicky